# How to access request parameters in Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to access request parameters on a web page and trying to set a hidden fields value to the passed parameter. How can I achieve this using struts2 tags?

Something like...

```
<s:hidden name="myfield" value="#parameters['myparam']"/>
```

I have tries using the parameters object but it does not work!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured this out. I was really lame to put this up here. Solution is shown below:

<s:hidden name="myfield" value="%{#parameters['mparam']}"></s:textfield>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding Zahieer's answer out of his comment so the question can be "answered":

```
<s:hidden name="myfield" value="%{#parameters['mparam']}"></s:hidden>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a String getMyParam(),setMyParam(String val) to the action rendering the form then you can use

```
<s:hidden name="myfield" value="${myParam}" />
```